# Open swipeable Fragment from RecyclerView.Adapter with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swipe, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` class with a `LinearLayoutManager`, which is dynamically loading more content as the user scrolls down. Each list item has a small preview image. When the user click the item, I open another Fragment where the full size image is loaded.

Instead of opening and closing each time I want to see another image, I want to be able to swipe the opened `ImageFragment` and have the next image loaded already. However, I don't see it as a solution to pass all the currently loaded objectIds from the adapter, since eventually the list of objects will be empty. How do I pass the dynamically loaded content from the adapter to the ImageFragment?

Should I create a method in the adapter I can call from the `ImageFragment` to get the next let's say 10 objectIds once the list on unviewed items go down to 5?

The data I fetch is sorted on distance, so I need to rely on the data in the adapter, because downloading the content from the DB directly will not necessarily provide the same order as the adapter has, if new items are created while being in the `ImageFragment`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `imageFragment` contains `RecyclerView` or `ViewPager` ?

Comment: Right now it is just a Fragment with an ImageView.

Comment: But you `Fragment` to behave like `Gallery` which can swipe left and right correct ?

Comment: I have been looking on some "Tinder-like" libraries, but I also want to be able to swipe down to close the ImageFragment. But yes, and then load more data as necessary from the adapter.

Comment: Then i think you should use either `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView` in your `Fragment`.

Comment: Let me gather my thought a bit then I may get you some answer.

Comment: Would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `RecyclerView` in your `Fragment` then you could add dynamic loaded object to `List` or `ArrayList` that you set up with the `Adapter` Then call `notifyDataSetChanged` after the item is added to the list. Or you could set up the same `List` of data to `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` as you use in the `Activity`

Sorry for any confusion or mistakes

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand your question, you want create something like a cache mechanism where you load previously some images that you're going to use in the next future. If you want that, you have to create a mechanism that take from adapter the position of your list, and you must take and save a number of images that you want and dinamically use and destroy images.

If I understand correctly your layout, i suggest also to see a master/detail flow, that hava a layout with a list on the left and a fragment on right in landscape mode, in portrait mode you have an activity with the list and another activity (when an item of list was clicked), with the fragment's detail inside.

Hope i help you ;)